# Uncertainty in Bayesian analysis application to security issues

Tags: networking

I am working on application of deep-learning in Vehicular communication security. I want to  get more ideas on how the uncertainty in Bayesian analysis can help to improve the detection accuracy in vehicular communication. For instance a situation whereby vehicles transmits both malicious and honest information among peer in a network and at the same time formulating new form of attacks having gained entrance into a network, since the whole thing is human driven.
The question is quite interwoven in the sense that it involves the  knowledge of vehicular network and deep learning. I humbly welcome ideas from the two domains.

Answer (score 0):

The models above can be used for applications as diverse as skin cancer diagnosis from
lesion images, steering in autonomous vehicles, and dog breed classification in a website
where users upload pictures of their pets. For example, given several pictures of dog
breeds as training data—when a user uploads a photo of his dog—the hypothetical
website should return a prediction with rather high confidence. But what should happen
if a user uploads a photo of a cat and asks the website to decide on a dog breed?

The above is an example of out of distribution test data. The model has been trained
on photos of dogs of different breeds, and has (hopefully) learnt to distinguish between
them well. But the model has never seen a cat before, and a photo of a cat would lie
outside of the data distribution the model was trained on. This illustrative example can
be extended to more serious settings, such as MRI scans with structures a diagnostics
system has never observed before, or scenes an autonomous car steering system has never
been trained on.

A possible desired behaviour of a model in such cases would be to
return a prediction (attempting to extrapolate far away from our observed data), but
return an answer with the added information that the point lies outside of the data
distribution. We want our model to possess some quantity conveying a high level of uncertainty with such inputs (alternatively, conveying low confidence).

To improve the detection accuracy in vehicular communication, you should not only have information about detection but also uncertainty.

Your question is quite broad so I am not sure my answer could help but you are welcome.